# Celery throwing pymongo.errors.ConfigurationError

Tags: python, django, mongodb, heroku

I have been using Celery with MongoDB for a month now with a Django Application. Here are the versions.

```
Django==1.8.4
celery==3.1.18
django-celery==3.1.16
pymongo==2.7
```

Everything was going fine for a some time but now everytime I run a task via task.delay() on the python shell on heroku,

```
pymongo.errors.ConfigurationError: command SON([('authenticate', 1), ('user', '*********'), ('nonce', '********'), ('key', '**********')]) failed: auth failed
```

As the error. Any inputs on what must be going wrong. I am pretty sure I have not made any changes to versions of any of these.

**UPDATE**

I am using MongoLab addon for heroku. I don't know what was the version when I installed it but mongod version is 3+ now which is obviously not supported by pyMongo < 2.7.
I wonder if Mongolab automatically changed the mongod version. I need mongod version to be  < 3.

Because celery doesn't support pyMongo  2.8+